# How to include all the AudioFormat in a RTP sequence?

Tags: java, rtp, javasound, payload, audioformat

I'm working on a Java project and my aim is to stream sound, using the RTP protocol. As a start, I wrote some code to generate the header, following the indications found in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol).

But now, I have many questions about the data payload : what do I have to send? I chosen a payload type 10 to stream sound using a wav format, sampled at 44.100 Hz in stereo.

But, in Java and probably in any reader, to read audio, other information is needed:

- the audio encoding technique (ex : PCM_SIGNED)
- the sample size in bits (ex : 16 bits)
- channels : 2, deducted by the payload type
- the frame size (16 bits * 2 channels = 32 bits = 4 bytes)
- the frame rate (supposed to be equal to the sample rate)
- endianess (ex : little endian)

All this information is coming with an object called `AudioFormat`. But, how to send that information with my payload? First, my receiver is probably not written in Java so, I doubt it understand the object `AudioFormat`. And, even if it is written in Java, how to indicate that the first payload part is an object `AudioFormat` and then, the raw data?

I suppose there's a "universal" way to send those informations but I didn't find anything on Google. Could you give me few tips?